# PHP | MYSQL : 2 or more columns for a single person

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling on how I could achieve this table.
I want the other batch of records to make another column just like in the picture below

[image]

this is my query:

```
    SELECT 
          stud_name, 
          equivalent 
    FROM tb_student_record 
    WHERE instructor_id = 'INST-20131296' 
          AND criteria = 'Quiz' 
          AND description = 'BIOETHICS' 
          AND subj_code = 'N049' 
          AND term = 'Midterm';
```

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: what you want to do?? Merge them(equivalent)?

Comment: please more detail, people need to be clear?

Comment: @FrayneKonok not merge, I want the other batch of records make another column

Comment: you can achieve the `concated form` from mysql, then `depart` it in php

Comment: @FrayneKonok any resources sir? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: is there unique id into the table?

Comment: @CallMeJeo, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Query:**

```
SELECT 
    stud_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(equivalent SEPARATOR '#') as equivalent
FROM tb_student_record 
WHERE instructor_id = 'INST-20131296' 
    AND criteria = 'Quiz' 
    AND description = 'BIOETHICS' 
    AND subj_code = 'N049' 
    AND term = 'Midterm'
GROUP BY `stud_name`;
```

Get the result in php and separate using `explode` function.
The function will work like:

> $equivalent = explode("#", $yourFetchArr->equivalent;) //depend on
>   your fetch, i use `mysql_fetch_object();`

Now `$equivalent[0]` and `$equivalent[1]` are the two separate equivalent;

Comment: @CallMeJeo, if the answer is useful then mark this as answer.

Answer (score -2):

You could do an subquery should look something like this

```
SELECT 
          stud_name, 
          equivalent,
          (SELECT 
               equivalent 
              FROM tb_student_record 
              WHERE instructor_id = 'INST-20131296' 
                AND criteria = 'Quiz' 
                AND description = 'BIOETHICS' 
                AND subj_code = 'N049' 
                AND term = 'Midterm';) AS equivalent2
    FROM tb_student_record 
    WHERE instructor_id = 'INST-20131296' 
          AND criteria = 'Quiz' 
          AND description = 'BIOETHICS' 
          AND subj_code = 'N049' 
          AND term = 'Midterm';
```

Then just change the inner query to select the details of your query. If you give me more details I could update my code to refect the innder query more correctly